# Path troubles when require or include file in PHP

Tags: php, require-once, php-include

I have directory structure like this:

```
 - index.php
 - templates(directory)      
     - login.php
 - header.php
 - js(directory)
     - jquery.min.js
```

I include script `jquery.min.js` in `header.php`, then I include `header.php` in `login.php`, but the path to `jquery.min.js` brokes. How I try to solve it by replace this:

`<script src="js/jquery.min.js">`

to this

`<script src="<?php echo dirname(__FILE__)?>js/jquery.min.js">` 
but then I get this path to resourse:

```
http://localhost/var/www/auth/js/jquery.min.js
```

And again 404 error. Can somebody explain to me how I can solve this issue.

Comment: have you tried this: <script src="../js/jquery.min.js">

Comment: @Vivek V Dwivedi, I need to define path, what will be automaticaly changes when I remove project to another folder, and I want to use jquery in another folder.This not solve my problen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

js's script files work in context of web-root. as long as your web-root is where your `index.php` is then `<script src="/js/jquery.min.js">` should work

You use `<script src="js/jquery.min.js">` which is a relative path. so, if you call `login.php` browser requests js relatively to it: `templates/js/jquery.min.js` which doesn't exist, obviously

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do is find the path of the javascript file relative to the root of your application, rather than any specific php file. So, if you change the script tag to begin with a `/`, it'll serve from the root of your application, regardless of where the php files are.

Changing it to `<script src="/js/jquery.min.js">` will serve it from `http://localhost/js/jquery.min.js` regardless of where in your structure your php files are.

Comment: ok, I set it to <script src="/js/jquery.min.js">  in header.php, but when I in login.php I still have the 404 error...the path in network is exactly http://localhost/js/jquery.min.js

Comment: @excluded_once does localhost/js/jquery.min.js serve ok? If so, and your script tags are set up as above, it should work from any page served on localhost. Is login.php on the same host? And when you inspect the network call in chrome's dev tools from where is it trying to load jquery.min.js?